# Authentication Required while sending a request to IIS from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, wcf, ipad, iis

I have a iPad application. In which I am making a proxy object using WCF data services(OData).

While initializing an object I am getting authentication required error. My service is authentication configured as windows authentication on the IIS 7.0.

Can anyone help me, How can I send windows credentials to get access of all the verbs (POST,GET,DELETE and etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure your service for anonymous access (or Basic authentication) if you want to access it from iPad. Windows authentication is only for devices which are part of your windows domain (or for local authentication).

Comment: Now I am getting Http Error 403 when I execute below code: [proxy addToObject:(id)object]; [proxy saveChanges];